# jquery UI "drop" have conflict with “sortable”？

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

My html is:

```
<div id="sortable">
    <div class="node"></div>
    <div class="node"></div>
    <div class="node"></div>
    <div class="node"></div>
</div>
```

My script is:

```
$('.node').droppable({
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        alert("drag finish");
    }
});

$('#sortable').sortable({
    stop: function (e, ui) {
        alert("sort finish!");
    }
});
```

But when I drag an element and sort, it only hits `alert("drag finish")` but not `alert("sort finish")`.

Why is this happening? How can I solve this problem?

Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/GRWDR/1/

Comment: can you put your code on jsfiddle

Comment: @Devjosh:I have edit ,look at the last line

Comment: The code in your jsfiddle doesn't match the code in this question. Which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i myself created a fiddle to test your problem and 
see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/devjosh/Vv7Jz/1/) it is working fine

> notice i load the scripts on dom ready i.e. i think you should enclose your scripts in dom.ready block

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.node').droppable({
                    drop: function (e, ui) {
                        alert("drag finish");
}
                })

$('#sortable').sortable({
                    stop: function (e, ui) {
                        alert("sort finish!");
                    }
                });

});
```

Hope this help you